# Recursively insert "22" between two repeated characters

Tags: c++, string, recursion

```
This is the homework spec
// Returns a string where the same characters next each other in
// string n are separated by "22"
//
// Pseudocode Example:
// doubleDouble("goodbye") => "go22odbye"
// doubleDouble("yyuu") => "y22yu22u"
// doubleDouble("aaaa") => "a22a22a22a"
//
string doubleDouble(string n)
{
 return ""; // This is not always correct.
}
```

This is part of a homework set that deals with recursion. I know how to use recursion with an int function but I'm not entirely sure how to approach this problem when a string is passed through. Is it as simple as n.length == n.length() +1 ? and then simply insert "22" ? Alongside this, how would one traverse the string? Thanks!

I would say that the base case be if n turns out to be just a blank space, or if it has a size 0, then simply return the string back, no changes made.

Comment: Please share what you have done so far.

Comment: Here is a hint: just focus on the first two characters and see what you can do with that.

Comment: Hi @LalitMehra, the only work I had was similar to Mihai's answer where I only worked on the base cases (string size is 0, and checking if the first two elements were a match). From here, my thought process was: if the first two characters are not a match, try the second and third, then third and fourth etc. Is that possible through recursion? Thanks!

Comment: My ultimate problem with this question is I'm not entirely sure how to go about iterating through a string recursively :( any hints would be appreciated

Comment: @stuckwithcs john's answer below will guide you with how to go about it recursively

Answer (score 0):

This seems OK to me (untested code)

```
string doubleDouble(string n)
{
    if (n.size() < 2)
        return n;
    else if (n[0] == n[1])
        return n[0] + ("22" + doubleDouble(n.substr(1)));
    else
        return n[0] + doubleDouble(n.substr(1));
}
```

As you can see you recurse on substrings of the original string.

Undoubtedly there are more efficient ways to do this (that minimise the string copying) but I'll leave that for you.

PS you need to enable C++11 to get all the required versions of `+` for strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
string doubleDouble(string n)
{
 if(n.length() == 2){
     if(n[0]==n[1])
        return n.insert(1,"22");
     else
        return n;
 }
 else if(n.length() == 1)
    return n;
 else
    if(n.length() % 2 == 1 || n[n.length()/2]!=n[n.length()/2+1])
        return doubleDouble(n.substr(0,n.length() / 2)) + doubleDouble(n.substr((n.length() / 2),n.length()));
    else if(n[n.length()/2]==n[n.length()/2+1])
        return doubleDouble(n.substr(0,n.length() / 2)) +"22"+ doubleDouble(n.substr((n.length() / 2),n.length()));

}
```

My solution uses 'Divide-and-conquer' paradigm to separate the string in 2 halfs again and again until it finds 1 or 2 characters only. The solution above is simpler. I tried an academic style.